# How to pickle or save a WxPython FontData Object

Tags: python, fonts, wxpython, pickle, wxstyledtextctrl

I've been coding a text editor, and it has the function to change the default font displayed in the `wx.stc.SyledTextCtrl`.

I would like to be able to save the font as a user preference, and I have so far been unable to save it.

The exact object type is `<class 'wx._core.Font'>`.

Would anyone know how to pickle/save this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably due to its nature, you cannot `pickle` a `wx.Font`.
Your remaining option is to store its constituent parts.
Personally, I store facename, point size, weight, slant, underline, text colour and background colour.
How you store them is your own decision.
I use 2 different options depending on the code.

- Store the entries in an `sqlite3` database, which allows for multiple
  indexed entries.
- Store the entries in an `.ini` file using
  `configobj`

Both `sqlite3` and `configobj` are available in the standard python libraries.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping you could pickle it but nvm.